# APScheduler Threading design pattern

Tags: multithreading, python-3.6, cx-oracle, apscheduler

I'm currently writing an application to schedule some metrics with APScheduler (3.6.0) and python3.6

After 5-6 days running, the scheduler stops without any error. So I thought it could be a ressource / concurrency problem.

I have different schedules like every 15 minutes, every 30 minutes, every hour etc...

My Scheduler is initilized as following and I am only using threads right now :

```
    executors = {
    'default': ThreadPoolExecutor(60),
    'processpool': ProcessPoolExecutor(5)
}

scheduler = BackgroundScheduler(timezone="Europe/Paris", executors=executors)
```

My question is the following : when multiple jobs start, passing through the same code part, can this be a potential conception mistake ? Do I need to put some lock then.
For example, they use the same code part to connect to a database (same module) and retrieve a result

```
def executedb(data):
    cursor = None
    con = None

    try:
        dsn = cx.makedsn(data[FORMAT_CFG_DB_HOST], data[FORMAT_CFG_DB_PORT],
                         service_name=data[FORMAT_CFG_DB_SERVICE_NAME])
        con = cx.connect(user=data[FORMAT_CFG_DB_USER], password=data[FORMAT_CFG_DB_PASSWORD], dsn=dsn)

        cursor = con.cursor()
        sql = data[FORMAT_METRIC_SQL]

        cursor = cursor.execute(sql)

        rows = rows_to_dict_list(cursor)


        if len(rows) > 1:
            raise Exception("")

    except Exception as exc:
        raise Exception('')
    finally:
        try:
            cursor.close()
            con.close()
        except Exception as exc:
            raise Exception('')

    return rows
```

Can this lead to threading concurrency ? And what is the best design pattern to do this ?

Comment: I am not familiar with APScheduler. Does it use multiple processes? Or multiple threads within the same process? Can you update your question accordingly?

Comment: @AnthonyTuininga you can choose whatever you want. I'm using a ThreadPool of 60 threads for my tests right now. I'm updating my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have multiple threads in your process, then when you connect to the database you should ensure that threaded mode is enabled, like this:

```
con = cx.connect(user=data[FORMAT_CFG_DB_USER], password=data[FORMAT_CFG_DB_PASSWORD], dsn=dsn, threaded=True)
```

Without that you run the very real risk of corrupting memory or causing other issues. Perhaps this is the source of your issues?

Another option is to use the new module [python-oracledb](https://oracle.github.io/python-oracledb/) which always has threaded mode enabled.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't knew about this one. I'll try this today !

Comment: After more than 1 week, it seems to work correctly :) 
Thanks for your answer

Comment: Great! Glad to hear it. :-)

Comment: There's no mention of a `threaded` argument in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-connectargs.html)?

Comment: The documentation you mentioned is for MySQL, not cx_Oracle. You can find one reference in the documenttaion [here](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_manual/module.html#cx_Oracle.connect). The [new module](https://oracle.github.io/python-oracledb/) no longer has the parameter as it is always enabled.